# Reversing the variable assignments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

If I have a string `"x1 = chyl_gi"`, where x1 and chyl_gi are both defined as symbolic variables, then the statement can be evaluated.

Typing in `x1` will result in the value `chyl_gi` being returned.
Typing in `chyl_gi` will result in `chyl_gi` being returned.

How do I change the evaluation of `"x1 = chyl_gi"` so that typing in `chyl_gi` will result in returning `x1`?  I can't change the order in how the variables are typed since I am working with a large text file in this format :

x1 = some var
x2 = another var
...

Comment: So there is no way to reverse assignments?

Comment: No. You'll have to write your code in a more sensible manner so that contortions like this are unnecessary.

Comment: I can't change the format in which these text files are handed to me...

Comment: I believe that is what one might call a [bi-directional mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map)...

Comment: Do you want `x1` to return `chyl_gi` or `x1`?

Comment: @excaza x1 should return chyl_gi as well.  A bidirectional map is exactly what I was looking for - but it seems that MATLAB doesn't have that as a native feature.

Comment: Okay, now I better understand what you want to do. You could parse each line and something like `x1=sym('chyl_gi');chyl_gi=sym('x1');` but this creates two independent variables, the symengine is not aware of any connection between both variables. Is this what you want? I don't see any use-case for this, if you are not sure describe the wider application. What do you want to do with these variables?

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, that works.  I'm working on a large sym cell where I need to substitute item names for variables like x1, x2, x3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now knowing your intended use, I recommend to use the `subs` function. Start parsing your text file to get the mapping:

```
syms x1 x2 chyl_gi chyl_gj a b c
mapping={x1,chyl_gi;x2,chyl_gj} %represents x1=chyl_gi and x2=chyl_gj;
```

And some example expression:

```
expr=x1+chyl_gi*(a+b+c);
```

Now you can simply use the subs function:

```
subs(expr,mapping,mapping(:,2:-1:1));
```

Which returns:

```
chyl_gi + x1*(a + b + c)
```

The advantage over the example in my comment above is, that you are really using the symbolic engine here.